# SELECT * with no tables specified is not valid

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I am receiving this error:

```
{
    "name": "error",
    "length": 189,
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "code": "42601",
    "internalPosition": "8",
    "internalQuery": "SELECT *",
    "where": "PL/pgSQL function insertintoinstancedlist() line 15 at RETURN",
    "file": "parse_target.c",
    "line": "1290",
    "routine": "ExpandAllTables"
}
```

and I'm unsure what's causing it as my trigger is the same another another with just a different table name. Here's the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
    insertIntoInstancedList () 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO
        creator.instanced_lists
        (
            list_id,
            account_id
        )
    VALUES
        (
            new._id,
            new.account_id
        );
    RETURN
        *;
END
$BODY$
language plpgsql;        

CREATE TRIGGER trig_list_insertion
    AFTER INSERT ON creator.lists
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE insertIntoInstancedList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. The `RETURN` needed to be `NEW`.

i.e.

```
INSERT INTO
    creator.instanced_lists
    (
        list_id,
        account_id
    )
VALUES
    (
        new._id,
        new.account_id
    );
RETURN
    NEW; <--- this here
```